# Installing Atom Editor SQLformat on a Mac for Beautify Package

Tags: atom-editor, atom-beautify

I have the Atom editor installed on my Mac, with the Beautify Package. Works great for HTML,etc, but when I try to Beautify SQL it says that it needs SQLFormat, which is not installed by default. When I follow the github link it shows that SQLFormat is Python, install instructions are downalod zip and 'pip install sqlparse'. Do I need to install Python to load sqlparse? Anyone have some simple instructions on how to load on a mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install sqlparse with pip ( to do this you need to have python)

`pip install sqlparse`

Once it's installed note down the python version with which its installed. e.g. in my case it was python3.7 / python3

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.4.2)
```

make sure `/usr/local/bin/` is on your PATH variable by running `echo $PATH` if not add it your PATH variable.

then create a file sqlformat under /usr/local/bin/ (i.e. /usr/local/bin/sqlformat) using any editor of your choice and paste below snippet, make sure to use correct version of python and save the file

```
#!/bin/bash
FLAGS="$f $p $@"

exec python3 -m sqlparse $FLAGS
```

finally do change the file permission by
`chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/sqlformat`